# How to install node.tar.xz file in linux

Tags: node.js, node-modules, npm-install

I recently downloaded the Nodejs file from the official site and I don't know how to install the Nodejs from a archived file.

Please help me how can I install this file so that I can run the "npm" command from the CLI for installation of several packages for my own project.

Comment: You might find it easier to use a package manager: https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/. If you really want to build from source see https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/BUILDING.md#building-nodejs-on-supported-platforms

Comment: This belongs to superuser.com. Maybe this can help you: https://superuser.com/questions/904001/how-to-install-tar-xz-file-in-ubuntu

Answer (score 250, accepted):

**Steps to download and install node in ubuntu**

Step 1: Download latest or recommended **node** .tar.xz file from https://nodejs.org/en/

or you can download node version 14.15.5 (.tar.xz file) directly from here ->

https://nodejs.org/dist/v14.15.5/node-v14.15.5-linux-x64.tar.xz

Step 2: Go to the directory in which (.tar.xz file) is downloaded.

In my case --> /Download directory

Step 3: Update System Repositories

`sudo apt update`

Step 4: Install the package xz-utils

`sudo apt install xz-utils`

Step 5: To Extract the .tar.xz file

`sudo tar -xvf name_of_file`

In my case -->  `sudo tar -xvf node-v14.15.5-linux-x64.tar.xz`

Step 6: `sudo cp -r directory_name/{bin,include,lib,share} /usr/`

In my case --> `sudo cp -r node-v14.15.5-linux-x64/{bin,include,lib,share} /usr/`

Step 7: Update the Path `export PATH=/usr/node_directory_name/bin:$PATH`
In my case --> `export PATH=/usr/node-v14.15.5-linux-x64/bin:$PATH`

Step 8: Check the node version

`node --version`

Result In my case -> `v14.15.5`

Comment: Not working for me

Comment: @FabioDev Did you get it right?

Comment: Perfect solution, and bonus points for the {,} style expansion. That's a useful bash trick I hadn't come across before.

Comment: for me `sudo cp -r node_directory_name/{bin,include,lib,share} /usr/` did not create a node_directory on the destination. Is that okay? So did not have to update the path

Comment: @vkt Same for me. I ran `node --version` and got `v18.9.1` which is what I downloaded so everything seems to be working.

Comment: Step  7 seems not needed, but it's a good answer :)

Comment: you could simplify steps 5,6,7 with `tar --strip 1 -xJvf "node-v v14.15.5-linux-x64.tar.xz" -C /usr/`

Comment: Where on Ubuntu does npm of node js installed in this manner (tarball -> unzip -> add bin to PATH) download packages to?

Comment: Well, now how to uninstall node in this way !?

Comment: is it better to be `sudo cp -r directory_name/{bin,include,lib,share} 
    /usr/directory_name`  in order to make step 7 point to the required path or step 7 won't be needed

Comment: This worked for me, after days of frustration, thanks.

Answer (score 20):

I got it installed with the below command. Don't include curly braces in the command. I place it in the command just for readability. You have to change the `download-directory` and `filename` according to your preference.

```
sudo tar --strip-components 1 -xvf {download-directory}/{filename}.tar.xz --directory /usr/local/
```

Comment: Great help here!  This is the simplest and de-facto answer for the question.

Comment: Great!! This worked for me too.

Comment: this works perfectly, use this

Comment: Awesome. Its much more clean way than with curly baraces.

Comment: Great!! worked well but can you explain how its working..... it amazes me know how it works

Answer (score 12):

i am new using linux, i use elementary for my old pc, so, i use

```
sudo apt install nodejs
```

and then

```
sudo apt install npm
```

but was a old version of node and npm so...`npm cache clean -f` and then `npm install -g n`

so the last thing i use `sudo n stable` and is all node v14 installed :)

Comment: The question specifically asks how to install from a tar ball. Using apt is not a helpful answer.

Comment: Yes, this is the easiest method. Thanks

Comment: This answer is a bit misleading too, or at least doesn't clarify everything. `n` is a package for managing nodejs versions, like `nvm`. So it installs the latest version of node via a whole versions manager lib, not via the tar file downloaded from nodejs itself.

Comment: `sudo apt install nodejs` already install npm. No need to run the second command.

Answer (score 7):

**Steps to download and install node in ubuntu/popos**

1. Download nodejs from
   https://nodejs.org/dist/v14.18.0/node-v14.18.0-linux-x64.tar.xz

Use cURL to download the TAR archive from the [nodejs.org](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/) website:

```sh
curl -L -o target/path/to/nodejs.tar.xz \
   https://nodejs.org/dist/v14.1xxxxx.tar.xz
```

2. Create the new NodeJS dir and extract TAR archive into it:

```sh
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/lib/nodejs \
   && sudo tar -xJvf node-v14.18.0-linux-x64.tar.xz \
   -C /usr/local/lib/nodejs
```

3. open terminal and execute below command

```sh
less ~/.profile
```

(Press q to quit less.)

Or:

```sh
gopen ~/.profile
```

Add below to profile

```sh
# Nodejs
VERSION=v14.18.0
DISTRO=linux-x64
export PATH=/usr/local/lib/nodejs/node-v14.18.0-linux-x64/bin:$PATH
```

1. Refresh profile
   . ~/.profile
2. Test installation using terminal:

```sh
node -v
npm version
npx -v
```

3. the expected output is something like:

```
v14.18.0
{
      npm: '6.14.15',
      ares: '1.17.2',
      brotli: '1.0.9',
      cldr: '39.0',
      icu: '69.1',
      llhttp: '2.1.3',
      modules: '83',
      napi: '8',
      nghttp2: '1.42.0',
      node: '14.18.0',
      openssl: '1.1.1l',
      tz: '2021a',
      unicode: '13.0',
      uv: '1.42.0',
      v8: '8.4.371.23-node.84',
      zlib: '1.2.11'
}
6.14.15
```

Comment: mkdir: invalid option -- 'x'

Comment: They forgot to put `&&` between the `mkdir` and `tar` commands, so the terminal thinks you want to use the `-x` flag with `mkdir`.

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer finally!

if anyone is struggling with **.tar.xz** files then follow the below steps for installation:

1. EXTRACT THE FILE (Use either terminal or right-click on the file and click "Extract here", file archive will extract the **xxxxxx.tar.xz** file and you will get a folder with the same your file name **xxxxxx**)
2. Copy the entire folder(**xxxxxx** folder) to **/usr**/

- you may need to **sudo** prefix to copy that folder into **/usr/**
- command to copy is
  #sudo cp -r /path-to-the-folder/xxxxxx(sub_folder_name-1,sub_folder_name-2,....) /usr/

There you go.now the program/software is installed and you can use it using your teminal.

Answer (score 2):

in the nodejs.org [download section](https://nodejs.org/en/download/), there is this link:
[Installing Node.js via binary archive](https://github.com/nodejs/help/wiki/Installation).
It has the steps written very clearly.

just replace the placeholders $VERSION & $DISTRO with its value.
AND during the second code of the first step make sure that you are on the directory where you have downloaded the node tar.xz file.

Answer (score 0):

Download the final version from https://nodejs.org/en/download/

Use this to extract it on the system:

> sudo tar --strip 1 -xJvf "node-v20.10.0-linux-x64.tar.xz" -C /usr/

or if you use conda, use:

> sudo tar --strip 1 -xJvf "node-v20.10.0-linux-x64.tar.xz" -C ~/miniconda3/

Then if you can't find `node` address it using:

> export PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH

or

> export PATH=/miniconda3/bin:$PATH

Thats it. Check the version with  `node -v`

Answer (score -1):

Install the latest version or LTS version

```
sudo apt install nodejs -y

sudo npm i -g n

sudo n latest
```

or `sudo n lts` if you want to install LTS version