# Can't use npx create-react-app with typescript template, "The react-scripts version you're using is not compatible with the --template option."

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, create-react-app, npx

I've tried to create a new react app with the typescript template with the following command:

```bash
npx create-react-app myReactApp --template typescript
```

But I only get a vanilla javascript react app and this message:

```bash
The react-scripts version you're using is not compatible with the --template option.
```

I've tried to update react-scripts, but I don't even have it and also think I shouldn't have to, because I'm not creating the app via create-react-app, but via npx and I couldn't figure out how to update the create-react-app in npx, if that's even possible.

I'm running npm version 9.6.6 and node version v18.16.0, so nothing outdated really.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71829863/why-npx-create-react-app-is-showing-the-project-was-bootstrapped-with-an-old-un Answer here also solved my shit. Dunno y, but did