# Project was bootstrapped with an old unsupported version of tools while creating react app

Tags: reactjs, node.js, npm, bootstrap-4, npx

I want to create a react app by using this simple command 
`npx create-react-app frontend` 

and get this warning

**Note: the project was bootstrapped with an old unsupported version of tools.
Please update to Node >=14 and npm >=6 to get supported tools in new projects.**

Here is the path of my node and npm

```
laptop:~$ which npx
/snap/bin/npx
laptop:~$ whereis npx
npx: /snap/bin/npx
laptop:~$ whereis node
node: /snap/bin/node
laptop:~$ whereis npm
npm: /snap/bin/npm
laptop:~$ node -v
v20.11.1
laptop:~$ npm -v
10.2.4
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question might already have an answer, please go to the provided stack overflow link.

[Check out this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71829863/why-npx-create-react-app-is-showing-the-project-was-bootstrapped-with-an-old-un)