# Creating custom gutenberg block gives 'Unexpected token .'

Tags: wordpress, content-management-system, wordpress-gutenberg

I am trying to create a custom gutenberg block to use in the wordpress gutenberg editor but when trying the command: `npx @wordpress/create-block test-block` it starts with installing a few things but all of a sudden I get:

```
npx: installed 126 in 13.341s
Unexpected token .
```

What is causing this?

I am following this tutorial: https://kinsta.com/blog/gutenberg-blocks/ except I am not using any of the hosting options from the tutorial since I have my own wordpress installation already running (locally).

Comment: Please share the code you have here so others can see what's going on (refer to [How to create a Minimum, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for more details.)

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem. All I needed to do was to update my Node version.

I followed these steps (run in Mac Terminal):

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

For folks on Ubuntu: I ran into the same issue and found that the nodejs installable via apt is out of date. I had to download the tarfile from nodejs.org and install it with the help of [How to install node.tar.xz file in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63312642/how-to-install-node-tar-xz-file-in-linux). After that it ran as I expected.

(I tried the LTS version. `node --version` returns `v18.12.0`)