# Why isn't @wordpress/create-block working?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-gutenberg

I am trying to create a gutenberg block scaffolding but this command is not working for some reason. I am running the below command and receiving the below message. How do I fix this? Node and npx are installed. I am confused as I do not have a period in my command.

```
npx @wordpress/create-block gcb-test-block
```

Message the terminal shows me:

> Unexpected token .

Comment: There's obviously more to the story than what you've shown us. Please revise to provide more context for your problem.

Comment: What version of node are you using?

Comment: likely outdated version of node (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74070868/creating-custom-gutenberg-block-gives-unexpected-token)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have not set wordpress development enviroment. make sure latest version of npm, nodeJs and run following command.

```
npx -g install @wordpress/env
```